# Can map a string literal type as key name in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if could map a string literal type as a key in new type.

I tried but it's not right.

```js
const a = {
  type: "key",
  actions: {
    a() {},
    b() {},
  },
} as const;

/* Map to
{
  key: {
    a() {},
    b() {},
  }
}
*/

type A = typeof a

type T = {
  A['type']: A['actions']
  // 'A' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can like this:

```
type T = {
  [K in A['type']]: A['actions']
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBjKBPADgUwC4YAiAa32xIBoN5goBLcCY9TTOACgEpUBfWhxgAjXgKExBafvAgxQkKAG40aAPQAqGAFk4uLCDTsYFbGzqdxKacLF8bk-jLSb1anARgBBJFjz4IABm8B4BMAAqfiYA2gDSMIxgPjEA5J74qQC6WcTeaXAMzJDZdOrqMKneqTDgADbYMABO+EH4TfJQIPD+BNSiAK6wjPIi+EkA5jADEPgAJnI9AG5wdQP4MAAW7fgAdFAQXABMAGwAnADMPC5AA)